# php domdocument exception loadHTMLFile

Tags: php, domdocument, fatal-error

I am having a *strange* behavior in my script. That has me confused

**Script 1.**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("html/signinform.html");//loads file here
$form = $dom->getElementsByTagName("form")->item(0);
$div = $dom->createElement("div");
$dom->appendChild($div)->appendChild($form);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

**Script 2.**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$div = $dom->createElement("div");
$dom->loadHTMLFile("html/signinform.html");//loads file here
$form = $dom->getElementsByTagName("form")->item(0);
$dom->appendChild($div)->appendChild($form);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

**Script 1** works **without problem**. It shows the form. However **Script 2** throws the **following error**: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Wrong Document Error' in C:\Users

Could someone explain to me why the mere changing of position of the loadHTMLFile function results in such error? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have added an element to the DOM (`div`) and then attempted to load a file to be parsed and its DOM structure used.

Load the file first if you intend to use one.

Comment: So you mean that in every script I must first load the file?

Comment: @Camilo Yes. What intention did you have for creating the `dom` element first?

Comment: I just thought I could dynamically load fragments of divs from existing html files and then insert them in the DOM where it was necessary.

Comment: @Camilo I think I have done that before, and used 2 `DOMDocument` objects to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For DOM manipulation you do not need to insert an already existing element so doing something like this: `$dom->appendChild($form)` only reinserts the same form element, when you pull an element using `$dom->getElementsByTag("form")->item(0)` it becomes it's own DOM object which you can reference directly and append to. A proper example would be:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("assets/dom_document-form.html");
$div = $dom->createElement("div");
$form = $dom->getElementsByTagName("form")->item(0);
$form->appendChild($div);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

One should append directly to the object they pulled from the DOM instead and load the document first.

To help aid your initial questions too:

- Append directly to element that you pulled as it references the object.
- `new DOMDocument` can be used to create multiple documents.
- using `DOMDocument::createElement` before `loadHTMLFile` creates 2 `DOMDocuments`.
- Using `DomDocument::createDocumentFragment` acts the same and creates it's own DOM.

If you would like to keep your code the same and create two `DomDocuments` then you should use `DomDocument::importNode`, an example of this would be:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$div = $dom->createElement("div");
$dom->loadHTMLFile("assets/dom_document-form.html");
$node = $dom->importNode($div);
$form = $dom->getElementsByTagName("form")->item(0);
$form->appendChild($node);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```